# Closed immersion → Pro-open immersion factorization for residual gerbes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, gerbes

Let $X$ be a quasi-separated algebraic stack.  Then it is a theorem of Rydh that every point $x$ in  $X$ admits a residual gerbe.  More or less, the construction proceeds by first taking the closure of the point, then finding an inverse system of dense open substacks of the closure with affine bonding maps, so the factorization $$\zeta_x\xrightarrow{i} \overline{x} \hookrightarrow X$$ is a factorization into a pro-open-immersion followed by a closed immersion. (The crucial point of the proof is that in the closure $\overline{x}$, there is a dense open substack that is a gerbe over some quasi-separated algebraic space, which has a dense open subscheme, and then we pull back the obvious system of affine open neighbourhoods to the gerbe).

For schemes, we have this factorization, but we also have the other factorization

$$x \hookrightarrow X_{(x)} \to X$$

factoring $x$ as a closed immersion followed by a pro-open-immersion (the Zariski-local scheme at the point).

This question could probably be phrased by asking if a quasi-separated algebraic stack admits a cofinal family of relatively affine opens around each point.  Then since residual gerbes exist in this situation, one might hope that there is a factorization

$$\zeta_x \hookrightarrow X_{(x)} \to X,$$

of the inclusion of the residual gerbe at $x$ as a closed substack of a 'local stack' around the point $x$.

Does such a factorization exist?  If it does, is there a name for this 'Zariski-local' stack at the point $x$?

If this is too much to ask, I am happy to assume that $X$ is Deligne-Mumford, quasi-compact, and even separated.